# Replace values in selected columns by passing column name of data.frame into apply() or plyr function

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a date.frame like:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=sample(1:5, 5, replace=TRUE), c=5:1)
df
  a b c
1 1 4 5
2 2 3 4
3 3 5 3
4 4 2 2
5 5 1 1
```

and I need to replace all the `5` as `NA` in column `b` & `c` then return to `df`:

```
df
  a b  c
1 1 4  NA
2 2 3  4
3 3 NA 3
4 4 2  2
5 5 1  1
```

But I want to do a generic `apply()` function instead of using `replace()` each by each because there are actually many variables need to be replaced in the real data. Suppose I've defined a variable list:

```
var <- c("b", "c")
```

and come up with something like:

```
df <- within(df, sapply(var, function(x) x <- replace(x, x==5, NA)))
```

but nothing happens. I was thinking if there is a way to work this out with something similar to the above by passing a variable list of column names from a data.frame into a generic `apply / plyr` function (or maybe some other completely different ways). Thanks~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=sample(1:5, 5, replace=TRUE), c=5:1)
df
var <- c("b","c")
df[,var] <- sapply(df[,var],function(x) ifelse(x==5,NA,x))
df
```

I find the ifelse notation easier to understand here, but most Rers would probably use indexing instead.

Comment: Great. Apparently I got it in a much convoluted way. Thanks!

Comment: And better to use `lapply` - no need for simplification here.

Answer (score 10):

You could just do

```
df[,var][df[,var] == 5] <- NA
```