# How to apply if condition in select columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `cc`. I want to apply if condition to change value above 50 as 50 and below zero as zero only in select columns(i.e only to column 3 and 4). I tried doing like this below but could not get what I need.

cc

```
 s.no       A        B       C       
    1         Inf     Inf      999.9
    2        -0.43    30       23
    3         34      -2       233
```

mycode

```
 if (cc[,3:4]>50){
      cc[,3:4]<-50
       }

if (cc[,3:4]<0){
      cc[,3:4]<-0
       }
```

result I want:

```
        s.no       A        B       C       
        1         Inf     50       50
        2        -0.43    30       23
        3         34      0        50
```

Comment: @Pascal yes I want to apply that condition only to columns 3 and 4; I want s.no and column 2 in the result as is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace values in selected columns by passing column name of data.frame into apply() or plyr function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991046/replace-values-in-selected-columns-by-passing-column-name-of-data-frame-into-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
cc[,3:4] <- sapply(cc[,3:4], function(col) ifelse(col>50,50,ifelse(col<0,0,col)))
cc
#   s.no     A  B  C
# 1    1   Inf 50 50
# 2    2 -0.43 30 23
# 3    3 34.00  0 50
```