# Replace values based on months in a dataframe with values in another column in r, using apply functions

Tags: r, if-statement, apply, weather

I am working with a time series of precipitation data and attempting to use the median imputation method to replace all `0` value data points with the median of all data points for the corresponding month that that `0` value was recorded.

I have two data frames, one with the original precipitation data:

```
 > head(df.m)
       prcp       date
1 121.00485 1975-01-31
2 122.41667 1975-02-28
3  82.74026 1975-03-31
4 104.63514 1975-04-30
5  57.46667 1975-05-31
6  38.97297 1975-06-30
```

And one with the median monthly values:

```
> medians
   Group.1         x
1       01 135.90680
2       02 123.52613
3       03 113.09841
4       04  98.10044
5       05  75.21976
6       06  57.47287
7       07  54.16667
8       08  45.57653
9       09  77.87740
10      10 103.25179
11      11 124.36795
12      12 131.30695
```

Below is the current solution that I have come up with utilizing the 1st answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991046/replace-values-in-selected-columns-by-passing-column-name-of-data-frame-into-app):

```
df.m[,"prcp"] <- sapply(df.m[,"prcp"], function(y) ifelse(y==0, medians$x,y))
```

This has not worked as it only applies the first value of the df `medians$Group.1`, which is the month of January (`01`). *How can I get the values so that correct median will be applied from the corresponding month?*

Another way I have attempted a solution is via the below:

```
df.m[,"prcp"] <- sapply(medians$Group.1, function(y)
                 ifelse(df.m[format.Date(df.m$date, "%m") == y & 
                 df.m$prcp == 0, "prcp"], medians[medians$Group.1 == y,"x"], 
                 df.m[,"prcp"]))
```

Description of the above function - this function tests and returns the amount of zeros for every month that there is a zero value in `df.m[,"prcp"]`
Same issue here as the 1st solution, but it does return all of the 0 values by month (if just executing the `sapply()` portion).

How can I replace all `0` in `df.m$prcp` with their corresponding medians from the `medians` df based on the month of the data?

Apologies if this is a basic question, I'm somewhat of a newbie here. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are dataframes same length? What years do the median month value correspond to?

Comment: The dataframes are not the same length. `df.m` is 504 rows, and `medians` is 12 rows (shown above). The median months do not have years, they are medians of that specific month for the entire dataset. These values I would like to put in my `df.m` where `df.m$prcp` == 0, based on the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider merging the two dataframes by month/group and then calculating with `ifelse`:

```
# MERGE TWO FRAMES
df.m$month <- format(df.m$date, "%m")
df.merge <- merge(df.m, medians, by.x="month", by.y="Group.1")

# CONDITIONAL CALCULATION
df.merge$prcp <- ifelse(df.merge$prcp == 0, df.merge$x, df.merge$prcp)

# RETURN BACK TO ORIGINAL STRUCTURE
df.m <- df.merge[names(df.m)]
```

Comment: This solution was very helpful and works with any filter (instead of changing values of 0, changing for all values < 15 for example. Can you explain why merging the two data frames will repeat the median values? My basic understanding was that to merge two data frames by columns, they had to be the same length.

Comment: Oh no, `merge()` is like SQL's `JOIN` and links recordsets by matching values of specific variables (i.e., `by` names). It will multiply for multiple matches per value. You are thinking of `cbind()` that requires equal length but by no match criteria.

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr version, which does not rely on original order. This uses slightly modified test data to show replacement of zeroes and multiple years

```
require(dplyr)

## test data with zeroes - extended for addtional years
df.m <- read.delim(text="
i prcp date
1 121.00485 1975-01-31
2 122.41667 1975-02-28
3 82.74026 1975-03-31
4 104.63514 1975-04-30
5 57.46667 1975-05-31
6 38.97297 1975-06-30
7 0 1976-06-30
8 0 1976-07-31
9 70 1976-08-31
", sep="", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

medians <- read.delim(text="
i month x
1       01 135.90680
2       02 123.52613
3       03 113.09841
4       04  98.10044
5       05  75.21976
6       06  57.47287
7       07  54.16667
8       08  45.57653
9       09  77.87740
10      10 103.25179
11      11 124.36795
12      12 131.30695
", sep = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)

# extract the month as integer
df.m$month = as.integer(substr(df.m$date,6,7))

# match to medians by joining
result <- df.m %>% 
  inner_join(medians, by='month') %>%
  mutate(prcp = ifelse(prcp == 0, x, prcp)) %>%
  select(prcp, date)

result
```

yields

```
       prcp       date
1 121.00485 1975-01-31
2 122.41667 1975-02-28
3  82.74026 1975-03-31
4 104.63514 1975-04-30
5  57.46667 1975-05-31
6  38.97297 1975-06-30
7  57.47287 1976-06-30
8  54.16667 1976-07-31
9  70.00000 1976-08-31
```

Comment: Why dplyr? Base's `merge()` and `ifelse()` could have done this as well.

Comment: Just personal preference for a more consistent set of data manipulation functions.

Answer (score 0):

I created small datasets with some zero values and added one line of code:

```
#create sample data    
prcp <- c(1.5,0.0,0.0,2.1)
date <- c(01,02,03,04)
x <- c(1.11,2.22,3.33,4.44)

df <- data.frame(prcp,date)
grp <- data.frame(x,date)

#Make the assignment
df[df$prcp == 0,]$prcp <- grp[df$prcp == 0,]$x
```

Comment: This assumes dates are in index order with median group and same size. We need OP to confirm this.